# Stored procedure output parameters return empty

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In my SQL Server 2014 I have a Stored procedure that returns 2 values in 2 variables as output:

```
@TotalNoRatio
@TotalRatio
```

Here are the results after execution:

```
@TotalNoRatio   @TotalRatio
34510793        31857292

Return Value 0
```

Now I want those 2 values to be display in a `Label` on my form.

Here is the code:

```
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@TotalNoRatio", SqlDbType.Decimal)
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@TotalRatio", SqlDbType.Decimal)
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
Me.LTotal1.Text = cmd2.Parameters("@TotalNoRatio").Value
Me.LTotal2.Text = cmd2.Parameters("@TotalRatio").Value
```

Everything runs fine without errors except that the results are empty.

Comment: You need to specify the direction of the parameter when you add them. The default is input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define direction as return something like this:

```
SqlParameter retval = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@TotalNoRatio", SqlDbType.Decimal);
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the direction of you parameters as `ParameterDirection.Output`. You will also need to declare your parameters on your procedure as `OUTPUT`.

I have put together a small example below.

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procedureName]  

@TotalNoRatio DECIMAL(18,2) OUTPUT,
@TotalRatio DECIMAL(18,2) OUTPUT

AS

SET @TotalNoRatio = 2
SET @TotalRatio = 3
```

This is my VB.NET code:

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(conString),
      cmd As New SqlCommand("procedureName", con) With {.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure}

    con.Open()

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@TotalNoRatio", SqlDbType.Decimal) With {.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@TotalRatio", SqlDbType.Decimal) With {.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output})

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    lTotal1.Text = "TotalNoRatio: " & cmd.Parameters("@TotalNoRatio").Value.ToString()
    lTotal2.Text = "TotalRatio: " & cmd.Parameters("@TotalRatio").Value.ToString()
End Using
```

This is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

On a seperate note consider turning [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement):

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

`cmd.Parameters("@TotalNoRatio").Value` returns type `Object`. You should be appending `.ToString()` to it if you're assigning to `Label.Text`.

Also note that I have implemented [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement). You may already have, it's difficult to tell but if you haven't it's worth doing:

> Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. A Using block guarantees the disposal of one or more such resources when your code is finished with them. This makes them available for other code to use.